# Named pipes in Java and multithreading

Tags: java, named-pipes

Am I correct I's suppose that within the bounds of the same process having 2 threads reading/writing to a named pipe does not block reader/writer at all? So with wrong timings it's possible to miss some data?

And in case of several processes - reader will wait until some data is available, and writer will be blocked until reader will read all the data supplied by reader?

I am planning to use named pipe to pass several (tens, hundreds) of files from external process and consume ones in my Java application. Writing simple unit tests to use one thread for writing to the pipe,  and another one - for reading from the pipe, resulted in sporadic test failures because of missing data chunks.

I think it's because of the threading and same process, so my test is not correct in general. Is this assumption correct?

Here is some sort of example which illustrates the case:

```
import java.io.{FileOutputStream, FileInputStream, File}
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class PipeTest extends FlatSpec {

  def md5sum(data: Array[Byte]) = {
    import java.security.MessageDigest
    MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(data).map("%02x".format(_)).mkString
  }

  "Pipe" should "block here" in {
    val pipe = new File("/tmp/mypipe")
    val srcData = new File("/tmp/random.10m")
    val md5 = "8e0a24d1d47264919f9d47f5223c913e"
    val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    executor.execute(new Runnable {
      def run() {
        (1 to 10).foreach {
          id =>
            val fis = new FileInputStream(pipe)
            assert(md5 === md5sum(IOUtils.toByteArray(fis)))
            fis.close()
        }
      }
    })
    (1 to 10).foreach {
      id =>
        val is = new FileInputStream(srcData)
        val os = new FileOutputStream(pipe)
        IOUtils.copyLarge(is, os)
        os.flush()
        os.close()
        is.close()
        Thread.sleep(200)
    }
  }

}
```

without **Thread.sleep(200)** the test is failing to pass for reasons

- broken pipe exception
- incorrect MD5 sum

with this delay set - it works just great. I am using file with 10 megabytes of random data.

Comment: You'll have to provide some context. Where'd you read that named pipes never block? This sounds counterintuitive, they're... well... pipes, not overflowing buckets.

Comment: Personally, missing data chunks sounds like your tests are wrong, you might be clobbering a stream buffer somewhere. Try using multiple *processes*, not threads for testing. Alternately, post a question with your test setup to ask why it would miss data chunks. (Which would make this an "XY problem" question. You should ask about the problem you're having, not your speculation on the cause or workaround.)

Comment: @millimoose I am not stating that named pipes are never blocking, but that's what I'm seeing in the test results. "Writer" thread may write 3 files to the pipe, and "Reader" can read only one of them. This is confusing.

Comment: A named pipe is a FIFO with a finite size. It will block if it is full and you are not doing a non-blocking write (and at that point your writes may interleave). You're ... doing something wrong. More info: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68146/what-are-guarantees-for-concurrent-writes-into-a-named-pipe

Comment: @jdevelop No, what you're saying is that a named pipe *silently discards data* when its buffer is full, and this sounds somewhat insane taken at face value. It's a valid approach to synchronisation: a lock-free bounded queue refusing to accept data instead of blocking, but that would usually be explicitly reflected in the API. (I.e. the API would include being able to tell if the queue is full, and whether an append succeeded.)

Comment: "Doing something wrong" may mean that it is not possible to use named pipe for reading/writing data in predictable manner within same process but different threads. Looks like this is true.

Comment: @jdevelop That would be ... completely false.

Comment: @jdevelop No, it's just that within the same process you're more likely to share some sort of IO buffer **by mistake**. (Whether you interpret the possibility of this mistake as evidence of unreliability of named pipes is up to you.) Testing with multiple processes will guarantee you're only sharing data through the pipe. And since your real use case also involves multiple processes, arguably that's what your test cases should do as well. It's not like there's a point to using named pipes to communicate within a process, that's what concurrent queues are for.

Comment: @jdevelop So my larger point is that when your test results are *counterintuitive* - which they are, silently losing data is unlikely to be an intentional design - you should first exclude problems in the test. Without seeing the test code, we can't really tell where the problem could lie, all I have to go on is you mentioning threads.

Comment: @millimoose I updated the post with the source code, perhaps it will make things more clear.

Comment: @parsifal If I open the pipe, then write some data to it, then close pipe - where's the race condition actually?

Comment: @jdevelop - Think it through. Pretend that your reader thread is blocked while two writes complete. Then pretend that your writer thread gets blocked halfway through a write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very simple race condition in your code: you're writing fixed-size messages to the pipe, and assuming that you can read the same messages back. However, you have no idea how much data is available in the pipe for any given read.

If you prefix your writes with the number of bytes written, and ensure that each read only reads that number of bytes, you'll see that pipes work exactly as advertised.

If you have a situation with multiple writers and/or multiple readers, I recommend using an actual message queue. Actually, I recommend using a message queue in any case, as it solves the issue of message boundary demarcation; there's little point in reinventing that particular wheel.

Comment: I think it's not the case, because I open pipe before read/write operation and close it afterwards. So shouldn't be a problem with race conditions at all.

Comment: I assume that it should prevent the second attempt of opening a pipe before until it is read completely.

Comment: @jdevelop -  Opening and closing the pipe does absolutely nothing to change the contents of the pipe. And it certainly doesn't serve as a synchronization point between your reads and writes. However, even it it did you'd have a race between the reads and writers. If you believe that the documentation says something different, please update your question appropriately.

Comment: I'm trying to understand. If process A opens the pipe P, and writes some data to it, then closes the pipe. The process B is reading the pipe P. **Before** process B finished reading of the pipe - process C **opened** the same pipe P and started to write to it. Does it mean that process B will get data from process A and process C as well? If so - then I'll need to find something else for my IPC.

Comment: @jdevelop - That's *exactly* how it works. A named pipe is simply a FIFO buffer of bytes. It provides no synchronization, other than at the syscall level (ie, a single write will be atomic).

Comment: ok, thanks, that makes it clear that this is simply race condition.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct I's suppose that within the bounds of the same process having 2 threads reading/writing to a named pipe does not block reader/writer at all?

Not unless you are using non-blocking I/O, which you aren't.

> So with wrong timings it's possible to miss some data?

Not unless you are using non-blocking I/O, which you aren't.

Comment: I believe this is subtly inaccurate. An "exhausted" named pipe wouldn't block waiting for more data, but return EOF instead, no?

Comment: @millimoose No inaccuracy, just a misconstrual on your part. I didn't say a read always blocks. I said the OP was wrong to say it never blocks.